# TimeZone Data updater(Java) to tzdata2016e

Tags: java, timezone

Due to tz-annoucement, my application need to update timezone data to tzdata2016e

Here provided two sources for update

1. ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tzcode-latest.tar.gz
2. ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tzdata-latest.tar.gz

The procedure steps are

1. I successfully update tzdata
2. when I updated tzcode, I encoutered an error as shown below

[image]

**The questions are:**
1. Why an error did occur?
2. What I have done wrong? Is it with the step of updating (tzcode before tzdata, or tzdata before tzcode)

Thanks for your help

**Edit:**

I use tzupdater.jar of Java to update tzdata. Refer to the document, it is for update tzdata not tzcode. How should I update tzcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't use tzcode. It has its own code implementation - in Java.

Tzcode is C source code for Linux, OSX, and other Posix operating systems.

You only need to run tzdata through the Java tzupdater.